# How to convert mapped variable into base64 string using Mirth

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

I have:

1. Raw xml filled by a select query.This xml transformed into a HL7
   message
2. One of the tags of this xml represents a clob column from a table in
   the database
3. I mapped this data (from edit transformer section) as a variable.
4. Now I am trying to convert this variable into a base64 string then
   replace it in my transformed hl7 message.
   5.I tried this conversion on a destination channel which is a javascript writer.

I read and tried several conversion methods like

```
Packages.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String();
```

I have got only error messages like :

```
EvaluatorException: Can't find method org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(java.lang.String);
```

Code piece:

```
var ads=$('V_REPORT_CLOB');
var encoded = Packages.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(ads.toString());
```

It is pretty clear that I am a newbie on that.How can I manage to do this conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use for Base64 encoding a string with your var substituted.

```
//Encode Base 64//
var ads = $('V_REPORT_CLOB');
var adsLength = ads.length;
var base64Bytes = [];

for(i = 0; i < adsLength;i++){
    base64Bytes.push(ads.charCodeAt(i));
}

var encodedData = FileUtil.encode(base64Bytes);
```

Comment: Hmm it seems  it doesnt raise an error bu I am getting null from encodedData when log it into server log and also at my updated column on the db :/

Comment: Is your variable 'ads' a clob or a string when you're trying to encode it?  When I have pulled clob data from a database it has first had to be converted to a string before any manipulation could be done.

    string = clob.getSubString(1,clob.length());